# Idiomatic way to return the element before an element that matches a function in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I have this input:

```
d=['List', 'of', 'devices', 'attached', '33ddd323514d7', 
   'device', '8742323455', 'device']
```

and I want to return all list elements that occur directly before an occurrence of a list element whose value is equal to `'device'` [which in this case would be the elements which correspond to the values of '33ddd323514d7' and '8742323455']. What is the best way to do this? Right now I do this:

```
[i[0] for i in zip(d[:-1],d[1:]) if i[1]=="device"]
```

Is there an easier more idiomatic way (or a standard library function) to accomplish this type of thing?

Comment: What are "the numbers" you want to return?

Comment: meant "list element", fixed above

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
d[d.index("devices") - 1]
```

**Edit:** Get all:

```
d[:d.index("devices")]
```

Comment: "I want to return the list element". Thats just one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator. Not a oneliner, but about 5 times faster.

```
def getPrevGenerator(l, e):
    if l:
        prev = l[0]
        for cur in l[1:]:
            if cur == e:
                yield prev
            prev = cur

def getPrevWithZip(l, e):
    return [i[0] for i in zip(d[:-1],d[1:]) if i[1]==e]


e = 'device'
d=['List', 'of', 'devices', 'attached', '33ddd323514d7', 
   'device', '8742323455', 'device']

import timeit, functools
n = 10000
print('getPrevWithZip %f' % timeit.timeit(functools.partial(getPrevWithZip, d, e), number=n))
print('getPrevGenerator %f' % timeit.timeit(functools.partial(getPrevGenerator, d, e), number=n))

>>>> getPrevWithZip 0.060799
>>>> getPrevGenerator 0.011307
```